# Rewrite my user id URL to a physical page on my website?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Good day,

I want to rewrite my user id URL to a physical page on my website.

This is a login PHP MySQL system and each user (client) has an ID assigned to them in MySQL. I want to give each user (client) a unique home page

So the client list are as follow:

```
Client1 - Client ID = 341
Client2 - Client ID = 342
Client3 - Client ID = 343
```

Currently, the user login to the site and gets redirected
from:
http://localhost:8888/report.mark1/user.php?id=341
to:
http://localhost:8888/report.mark1/341 (this works perfectly)

But I want to change this to the following:

From: http://localhost:8888/report.mark1/341
To: http://localhost:8888/report.mark1/client1/home

I want to do this for the other clients as well:

From: http://localhost:8888/report.mark1/user.php?id=342
To: http://localhost:8888/report.mark1/client2/home

From: http://localhost:8888/report.mark1/user.php?id=343
To: http://localhost:8888/report.mark1/client3/home

this is the current .htaccess file code:

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteBase /report.mark1/
##External redirect change of URL rules here.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(report\.mark1)/user\.php\?id=(\d+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=301,L]

##Internal rewrite to user.php rules here.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(?:[^/]*)(\d+)/?$  /report.mark1/user.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I hope this helps a bit more :)

Comment: For `From: http://localhost:8888/report.mark1/user.php?id=342 To: http://localhost:8888/report.mark1/client2/home` could you please explain how its deciding which request should go to which client? Thank you

Comment: So you want to get the `2` in `client2` from that last digit of `?id=342`, and vice versa the `3` in `client3` from `?id=343`? Please be explicit in your _explanation_, instead of giving "examples" that still require guesswork on our end.

Comment: @AnrichMark1, Thanks for updating post, so can this be assumed that you are taking last digit from `341`, `342` and so on for your client?

Comment: jip thats correct, if there are more users added the ID's will be 344, 345 etc

Comment: @AnrichMark1, ok but what will happen if your client values are going more than 10? Like `3410` will be there in query string? OR more than 9 value can't be there at all? Kindly confirm once, thank you.

Comment: Can it go to 350? I'm adding the user manually to the MySQL database and can assign any ID to the user, as this is not open to the public but only for our clients

Comment: @AnrichMark1, ok so you mean values should be always picked the last digit out of values from query string correct? Sorry why I am asking again so that there are no confusions :)

Comment: no worries, thanks :) jip thats correct

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, attempts please try following .htaccess rules. Make sure your .htaccess file is present alongside with report.mark1 folder and your user.php is present inside report.mark1 folder.

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteBase /report.mark1/
##External redirect of url in browser rules here...
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(report\.mark1)/user\.php\?id=(\S+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/home? [R=301,L]

##Internal rewrite of url to user.php file here...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(?:[^/]*)/([^/]+)/.*/?$ /report.mark1/user.php?id=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works, the only thing is I have to add the .PHP extension in the browser before the content shows :)

Comment: @AnrichMark1, ok sure, what is the link you are hitting?

Comment: if I go to this link: http://localhost:8888/report.mark1/client1/home

Comment: Oh I think I get something else: the client1, client2 and client3  the number should not be dynamically inserted because this is just a placeholder for the client name, lets say the client name is Ford (as an example)

So the link will be: http://localhost:8888/report.mark1/ford/home

Comment: @AnrichMark1, so you mean whatever comes after `?id=` should come in link?

Comment: thats correct :)

Comment: @AnrichMark1, ok sure, could you please try my edited code once and let me know it this helps?

Comment: Hi @RavinderSingh13 everything redirects perfectly, the only thing that I'm still a bit struggling with is the .PHP extension. the page redirects to the page without the .PHP extension, I need to manually add the extension in the website browser before the content shows

Comment: @AnrichMark1, wondering why its happening. Could you please do let me know if you have any other rules also present apart from these mentioned ones?

Comment: Hi, nope I only have your code in my .htaccess file

Comment: @AnrichMark1, ok what sample url you are hitting and what url its becoming in browser?

Comment: when I login with my user account it redirect to this page: http://localhost:8888/report.mark1/341/home I have to add the .PHP manually so that it reads like this: http://localhost:8888/report.mark1/341/home.php

Comment: @AnrichMark1, ok but actual url(before redirection) are you hitting? Since my code assumes you are hitting like `http://localhost:8000/report.markuser.php?id=bla_bla` something like that.

Comment: what i can do is share the github link: https://github.com/AnrichMark1/report.mark1

Comment: @AnrichMark1, could you please post actual/sample link which you are hitting that will help me more to understand your question better, Thank you.

Comment: @AnrichMark1, could you please try my updated rules once and let me know if these help you? cheers.

Comment: Hi I managed to solve the problem by creating another solution: see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72309642/redirect-based-on-the-id-parameter-in-the-url

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help, I learned a lot in the process :)

Comment: @AnrichMark1, your welcome, so it solved without htaccess rules? By php code?